# Точка в аргументах функции md5()

Tags: php

```
$save= md5( md5($salt) . md5( $new_pass ) );
```

Что в данном случаи делает точка? И как получить строку хеш, который выводится в переменную $save?

Comment: Это вопрос на ХэшКод.    echo $save;//ваша строка с хэшем

Answer (score 1):

Точка — конкатенация, объединяет две строки. Можно делать md5(сольпароль), а можно md5(md5(соль)md5(пароль)), кому как нравится.А вопрос про "как получить" я так и не смог понять. Не могли бы Вы по-русски его переписать?Нужно получит пароль из хэша? Крайне ресурсозатратно и очень проблематично.

Comment: нет мне не нужно получить пароль из хеша, я пишу программу на другом языкедля небольшого контроля за сайтом в ней хочу организовать и замену паролей в случаи не обходимости.